# A Ruby-on-Rails bug with CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone know why RoR isn't serving the CoffeeScript correctly?

in my application view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

in the browser, this shows up as:

```
<script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I click on that link, defaults.js is not found.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }

    body, p, ol, ul, td {
      font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:   13px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    pre {
      background-color: #eee;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 11px;
    }

    a { color: #000; }
    a:visited { color: #666; }
    a:hover { color: #fff; background-color:#000; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>No route matches [GET] &quot;/assets/defaults.js&quot;</pre></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rails 3.0, this `:defaults` argument was actually what was known as a *JavaScript expansion*, configured by Rails to expand out to include the Prototype files at *public/javascripts*.

In Rails 3.1, there is no longer these JavaScript expansions, but rather there's *manifest files*. Therefore you should not be using `javascript_include_tag :defaults` for this, but rather `javascript_include_tag :application`, which is the default JavaScript manifest file for your application.

In a default Rails 3.1 application, there's a `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file which contains directives for Sprockets for which files to require. I've [begun work on an Asset Pipeline guide](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html) for Rails which explains how these files work and what the directives mean.

Comment: There have never been `defaults.js` in Rails. Symbol `:defaults` just was expanded into javascript library files (e.g. `prototype.js` and so on) plus `application.js`.

Comment: @Seymon: Dang, you caught me when I was in the middle of an edit! I've cleaned it up now. How's it look?

Comment: The documentation you wrote is good.I have some follow up questions that I'm going to put in another URL.

Comment: Here's a follow up... might want to clarify the section of your documentation where you describe the application.js file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543104/how-does-ruby-on-rails-asset-pipeline-find-these-files

Comment: (I'm sure it all makes sense if you're coming from an earlier version of RoR and used Sprockets, but I'm new to RoR so I'm a good tester for the documentation.)